# Primary table data deleted with out deleting foreign table data

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-9.6

Hello I am using postgresql 9.6 and there is a table transactions.denominations table with primary key deno_id column and in other table there is transaction_detail table column with deno_id which is REFERENCES transactions.denominations(deno_id) but today accidentally I didn't get any data in denomination table but still there is deno_id value in transaction_detail table I am shocked this type of result. Please help how it happens?

Comment: It could be data corruption. Is the constraint valid? Was `session_replication_role` set to `replica`?

Comment: yes constraint is valid, while running delete query i unable to delete from primary table

Comment: Look in `pg_constraint` to see if the constraint is valid. Invalid constraints are also checked.

Comment: ALTER TABLE transactions.transaction_details
    ADD CONSTRAINT transaction_details_deno_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (deno_id)
    REFERENCES transactions.denominations (deno_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION;

Comment: I mean query [this table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html).